# Errors: Only integers, slices [...] and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices // Tensor object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, glcm

Trying to build a custom keras layer for GLCM, which requires to count pairs of pixels before doing further calculations, gets me the error below. The algorithm works just fine outside keras context.

**Error 1**

```
Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got <tf.Tensor 'glcm_layer_impl/strided_slice:0' shape=(150, 1) dtype=float32>
```

I understand, that `i,j` at the end of the loop are not integers with pixels values in graph mode, but SliceTensors. So I tried casting it to `int()`, but just to realize I get a CastTensor object instead.

**Layer definition:**

```
class GLCMLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, greylevels=32, angle=0, name=None, **kwargs):
        self.greylevels = greylevels
        self.angle = angle
        super(GLCMLayer, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)

    def _glcm_loop(self, image, angle, levels, out):
        rows = image.shape[1] # batch dimension is first entry
        cols = image.shape[2]
        offset_row = round(sin(angle))
        offset_col = round(cos(angle))
        start_row = max(0, -offset_row)
        end_row = min(rows, rows - offset_row)
        start_col = max(0, -offset_col)
        end_col = min(cols, cols - offset_col)
        for r in range(start_row, end_row):
            for c in range(start_col, end_col):
                i = image[r, c]
                row = r + offset_row
                col = c + offset_col
                j = image[row, col]
                out[i, j, 0] += 1 # here the errors occur 

    def call(self, inputs):
        P = tf.experimental.numpy.zeros((self.greylevels, self.greylevels, 1), dtype=np.uint32) # using np.zeros() will yield a different error
        self._glcm_loop(inputs, self.angle, self.greylevels, P)
        return P
```

Trying different way likes `eval()` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357542/attributeerror-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-numpy), didnt't help me either.

Then I tried `out[0,0,0]+=1` just to see if that works, but didn't:

**Error 2**

`'Tensor' object does not support item assignment`

Now I learned that Tensors are immutable. I tried other ways to get around it: using tf.Variables or using plain python object [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707385/typeerror-tensor-object-does-not-support-item-assignment). Yet I cannot think of a way on how to create a list and increase a counter for each pair of found pixels, because or Error 1.

Either way it always ended up with the first or second error. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543248/how-to-manipulate-tensor-array-tensor-object-does-not-support-item-assignment) seems to be the best idea, to get around it. Coming mostly from OOP programming, I cannot think of all the tf-functions I need here. I will try to get to know these functions, but maybe somebody already has an idea to get along without the tf-functions.

Greatly appreciate any help on how to resolve above errors.
Let me know if there is more than I can add to this question.

Input images are grayscale with 32 values and batched.

**Model definition:**

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
model = GLCMLayerImpl()(inputs)
model = layers.Flatten()(model)
model = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(model)
outputs = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(model)
```